# python:Data insertion error in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I have data that I need to insert into SQL Server in a list

```
values = [('Hello', 'McDonald'), ('Hi', 'Jennifer'), ('Ola', 'Janice'),('Hey', 'Bob')]
```

And I' trying to insert this using the following command:

```
columns_list_template = ','.join('[%s]'*len(noofcolumns))  # In this case 'noofcolumns' = 2
sql = 'INSERT INTO test VALUES ({0})'.format(columns_list_template)
cursor.execute(sql,values)
```

And I get the following error when I execute the code:

```
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('HY000', 'The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 10 parameters were supplied')
```

I'm really stuck and don't know where there is an error.
PS. The list can contain more than 100000 records also. It's very dynamic

EDIT:Thank you everyone for trying to  help me out. I had different datatypes defined in source and destinations and hence the problem. Couldn't have found it out myself. Thanks for always helping me out

Comment: Hint: print out what's in `values`. It's certainly not what you intended.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for replying. The data in values that I posted is what is displayed when I print `values`

Comment: Well, you've redefined it in your second snippet.

Comment: @sleepcoffeedelight - can you print the entire Insert query after replacing the values list

Comment: @sleepcoffeedelight - how many columns present in `test` table

Comment: @DanielRoseman oh I get it. I'm sorry. I'll just correst the mistake and get back. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Prdp 2 columns in the table. The out put you asked is : 
`INSERT INTO test VALUES (%s,%s)`

Comment: @sleepcoffeedelight - Better to add the insert column list as well. Tomorrow someone add a new column in `test` table your query will fail

Comment: @Prdp Yeah I'll do that too. I just wanted to first see if I can insert anything. Thanks alot

Comment: @DanielRoseman `pypyodbc.DataError: ('22001', '[22001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated.')`
This is the error I'm getting

Comment: cursor.executemany()

Comment: @wasp I've used a for loop to iterate over the list and make insertions. Will that degrade the performance